# MyApp/lib/ directory: How to use it right way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

The Guide says about /lib directory:

> lib/  - Extended modules for your application.

Somewhere I read that I could place my custom email validator class there. But how to use it then? How to require it?

Now I do this way:

```
# File with validator: MyApp/lib/myEmailValidator.rb
class EmailValidator
    def self.validate(email) ...
end

# In my "create" method, MyApp/app/controllers/hello_controller.rb
def create
    require "myEmailValidator"
    @result = EmailValidator.validate(params[:email_from_form])
end
```

It works, but is there a better way to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need at present is about validation, say email or anything else, yes, there is better practice.

1. Such logic should be in Model instead of Controller. If you want client side validation you can use Javascript, but there is no way to put those into controller.
2. For validation in model, ActiveRecord has tons of built-in methods. You can read them here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html. For your specific problem of email validation, that could be done by a pattern match like this:

   ```
   validates :email, presence: true, format: {with: /EMAIL_PATTERN_REGEX/}
   ```

If you need is about how to extend Rails core. Your method works, but better with Module, or Class under Module to add extra namespace and avoid name conflict.